# display variable wth function have a name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display variable using `document.write()` method.
My code is

```
var x = function name(){var x = "anyname" return x;};
document.write();`
```

My question is: what is code I should have to use in `document.write()`portion to display **var x** .
Thank you.

Comment: simple. just write document.write(x);

Comment: Actually, since it's a function, you'll want to write document.write(x())

Comment: @Oscar is wright, you have to call `document.write(x());`...

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by **var x**.

You’ve got a global `x` (the function `name`) and a local `x` (the string “anyname”). Neither one of them will print a “x” literal, nor will the `var` keyword. From the `x` that you have, you can print things like:

```
var x = function name(){ var x = "anyname"; return x;};
document.write( x );      // like uneval() => “function name(){var x = "anyname"; return x;}”
document.write( x() );    // invocation;   => “anyname”
document.write( x.name ); // Function.name => “name”
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your kind information.I have now get the clear concept about it .

Comment: @foysalsheykh: You are welcome. If this answer was helpful, consider marking it as accepted answer. See also: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).